# Rails polymorphic association is inserting an extra field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I created a migration to change my data model, in order to make my Conversation model polymorphic.

Here are my files, slimmed down:

```
# deal.rb
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversations, as: :conversationable
end

# conversation.rb
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :conversationable, polymorphic: true
end
```

In my seeds.rb, I am calling the line:

```
conversation = deal.conversations.create!(:seller_id => deal.user.id, :buyer_id => user.id)
```

Which generates the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table conversations has no column named deal_id: INSERT INTO "conversations" ("buyer_id", "conversationable_id", "conversationable_type", "created_at", "deal_id", "seller_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Why is rails still inserting deal_id? Are there remnants of the association elsewhere that I have to delete?

When running the same code in rails console, the model is created with the correct associations.

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure it's failing where you think it is? sounds like an outdated fixture file

Comment: is there an old association in Deal class with conversations without the `as` option?

Comment: @firien: yep! I looked at the logs and tracked it down to that exact line.

Comment: @tihorn: I had this thought as well - it's the only association to conversations in that class.

Comment: are you sure you run your migration (in the test database)? if so can you show it?

Comment: @polmiro: Yep, migrated properly -- the schema looks correct

Comment: could you try running rake db:test:prepare first and then execute the specs

Comment: I never use the test database, this is all in development. I don't currently have any tests written, so running the specs will do no good.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://gist.github.com/radar/6503866. Please provide steps to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out (Thanks to Ryan Biggs).

The problem was that to reset my application, I was calling

```
rake db:drop && rake db:migrate && rake db:seed
```

which didn't give enough time for the column information to be reloaded between migrating and seeding.